# How to load prefab properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to instantiate a Prefab by it's name (and path), which comes from my server, from my Assets folder and came across some issues.
I found multiple ways of doing this:

```
var prefab = Instantiate(Resources.Load("prefabName")) as GameObject;
```

This is suggested by most threads but as described [here](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/resources-folder) you should not use it.

```
var prefab = Instantiate(UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(path));
```

This is the second way I found but this will only work when working inside the Editor. Building the project to a WebGl for example will immidiatly throw a build error.

So what is the proper way to instantiate a prefab then?

Comment: As you can see, the second approach use "UnityEditor" as source of asset. It makes sense, it doesn't work outside the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply add a (serializable) field in your MonoBehaviour:

`[SerializeField] private GameObject myPrefab;`

or

`public GameObject MyPrefab;`

Drag your prefab in the inspector, then below in your code:

`GameObject clone = Instantiate(myPrefab);`

The difference with this approach is that your prefab is preloaded in memory, i.e. when you instantiate you read from memory (as opposed to disk).

Comment: The problem is, that the prefabs name comes from the server, so Unity will not know it's name when running.

Comment: I can't help much with the networking stuff. Just an idea without me having any real experience with that: Maybe preload all prefabs(or better load/unload bundles containing only the currently possible options) and then have some system that gets the name from server and returns current prefab reference. Or simply use your first approach. And it again goes down to a memory/performance trade-off.

Comment: Well the server stuff is quite simple, this is not the problem. All I need is the correct way to load the prefab by it's name.

Answer (score 2):

Are you importing assets into your already built game? Or are you refering to assets that are already in your project?

Because if you want to **import on runtime** you could use AssetBundles. Unfortunately I can't really help you with that since I have no real experience on working with them, but I have read somewhere that many mobile devs use them to distribute their asset on game launch.

Maybe the [Asset Bundle Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) helps you with that.

If you want to Instantiate prefabs that are **already in your project** you could use a `Dictionary<string,GameObject>`. Like that:

```
public Dictionary<string, GameObject> prefabDict = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();


public void SpawnPrefabFromDict(string name)
{
    Instantiate(prefabDict[name]);
}
```

The string as key then point to its value - your prefab!

Hope this helps!
Good Luck!

Comment: But how do I get the GameObject when running as WebGL?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "get the GameObject". Could you explain in a bit more detail?